# Not able to access data into a journey builder to use in flow control

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We have a small set of data extension models but we are struggling to get contact data we want into our journey. Does journey only let you access contact data related to a particular contact? Is there any way I can get a row from a data extension which belongs to a different contact? If we can not do that then we really can't use any journey builder for our project.

E.g.

For our business, we create load match recommendations for carriers but actual loads are created by a shipper user.
We are trying to create a journey for a carrier for one load match recommendation as an entry point. But we need to put flow control on load which mostly belong to a different contact(a shipper). We want to access this load into our journey, but we are not able to. Since load belongs to a different contact, we are not able to access it from the contact data provided by the journey builder.

Please advise! This is a very urgent issue.